# Div Not displaying on hovering

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display some content in  div tag when hovering on the menu. Here I am trying to display a div when hovering on About. But it does not work.Kindly only check the commented portion. Ignore rest!

Here is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/styling.css">
<head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<header class="head-nav">
<a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="Images/Logo.jpg"></a>
<nav class="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

<!––The hovering Menu––>
<li class="dispmenu"><a href="#">About</a></li>

<li ><a href="#">Center</a></li>
<li ><a href="#">Team </a></li>
<li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<ul>
</nav>
</header>
<div class="submenu">
Hello
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
.container {
width: 1000px;
height: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 1px solid gray;
}
header {
overflow: hidden;
}
.logo {
float: left;
}
.navigation ul {
list-style: none;
}
.navigation ul li {
background-color: #e0e0d1;
margin-top: 40px;
width: 96px;
border: 1px solid lightblue;
height: 40px;
text-align: center;
float: left;
}
.navigation ul li a {
font-size: 11px;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
color: #2485ba;
}
.active {
color: #2485ba;
}
/*the css for hiding and displaying*/
.dispmenu:hover .submenu {
visibility: visible;
}
.submenu {
background-color: darkblue;
color: white;
width: 684;
height: 100px;
margin-left: 312px;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You will need to include the submenu in the list item itself or directly after it, because CSS can't go and search the whole page. Take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp)

Comment: Unrelated, make sure to close your head and ul tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a jQuery option if you go that route..

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/ns6j55zg/

You can read about `.hover` [here](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```js
$('.dispmenu').hover(function() {
    $('.submenu').addClass('dispmenu-hover');
}, function() {
    $('.submenu').removeClass('dispmenu-hover');
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  /*width: 1000px;*/
  /*height: 1000px;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
header {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
}
.navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
display: flex;
}
.navigation ul li {
display: flex;
  background-color: #e0e0d1;
  margin-top: 40px;
  /*width: 96px;*/
flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
.navigation ul li a {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex: 1;
text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  color: #2485ba;
}
.active {
  color: #2485ba;
}
.submenu {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  width: 684;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 312px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
/*the css for hiding and displaying*/
/* this class moved to appear after .submenu class */
.dispmenu-hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <header class="head-nav">
    <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="Images/Logo.jpg"></a>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <!––The hovering Menu––>
        <li class="dispmenu"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Center</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="submenu">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  .dispmenu:hover .submenu {
> ```

You have a space between those selectors. A space is a [descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators).

The element `<div class="submenu">` is not a descendant of the element `<li class="dispmenu">`. It is a sibling of the great-grandparent of the list item.

CSS selectors provide no way to describe going **up** the DOM tree, so you can't achieve this without either:

- Changing the structure of the DOM
- Using JavaScript

Ideally you should do both since:

- It doesn't make much sense for a submenu to be completely disconnected from the menu item it is for. Think about how [that type of data is normally represented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvRBL.png).
- You can't put in things like time delays before a menu vanishes, which makes a menu like the one you are trying to create challenging for people with some accessibility needs (e.g. sufferers of arthritis who many struggle to move the mouse in a straight line and keep the pointed inside the borders of the menu).